# Using StackExchange as Q&A System on Current Website

Tags: discussion, edits, stack-exchange, redirection, hosting

I am looking to integrate a Q&A script into a large website I am working on and StackExchange would be a great fit for us.

The only issue we have is the level of control we would like to have on the Q&A application itself. We would most likely want to place adverts on pages or custom HTML for forms in the sidebar, and we would definitely want it "located" on our website (i.e. http://www.ourwebsite.org/ask/). We run our site on ASP.NET and sadly a lot of the open source alternatives are written in PHP with MySQL in mind.

I apologise if this is the wrong place to ask this, but what level of control would StackExchange offer us? Can I redirect a SE page to our own domain and how much control will I get over additional HTML for adverts or forms within the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would have been Stack Exchange 1.0; the product has been discontinued for almost a year now.

As far as I know, there is still a version sold by Stack Exchange, Inc. *for intranets only* however.

Comment: So, websites like askubuntu.com and answers.onstartups.com are all part of SE1.0 and that option is no longer available to them?

Comment: @Ender No; they're SE 2.0 sites. They do not support custom HTML/JS like you require. Actually I don't think SE has ever supported custom HTML.

Comment: That's a shame. However, without this requirement would it be possible to have a SE site redirect to mydomain.com/ask?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to go with one of the [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones).

Comment: I've been looking for a good ASP.NET alternative, and sadly the ASP.NET and C# clones mentioned look abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your solution: www.expertbase.com